# jQuery triggering fadeIn and fadeOut issue

Tags: jquery

I have a container element with other elements inside it. If I move the mouse over this wrapper element I would like to fadeIn a `<div>` element located inside this element, and fadeOut when the mouse leaves the wrapper. My problem is that the fadeIn and fadeOut seems to be called multiple times, because the element starts blinking (fade in and out several times) as I move in or out the mouse. Here is my source code:

```
<div class="panel_body">
   <div class="chb_input_row">
      <div class="row_wrapper">
         <label>user</label>
         <input type="hidden" value="1" name="user_profiles">
         <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user_profiles">
         <div class="description">
            <div class="tool_tip tool_tip_animated tool_tip_after" style="display:none;">Something</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".chb_input_row").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find('.tool_tip_animated').fadeIn();
        });

        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find('.tool_tip_animated').fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

So what I want is when the mouse over action is triggered by the `.chb_input_row` make the `.tool_tip_animated` to fadeIn and vice versa.

I have tried the `hide()` and `animate()` methods of jQuery but no one worked properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) events will fire when the mouse moves to child elements. The solution is to use the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events respectively.

You can use the [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) utility function to do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".chb_input_row").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.tool_tip_animated').fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.tool_tip_animated').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

- [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)
- [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout)
- [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)
- [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of `mouseover`:

```
$(this).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.tool_tip_animated').fadeIn();
});
```

It will fire only once when mouse reach the container